# Use multiple condition in Process.GetProcesses().Where(Title == args[0] and ProcessName == args[1]")

Tags: c#

I'm currently using:

```
String Title = args[0].ToLower()+ " - Notepad";

Process process = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.MainWindowTitle
                                                == Title).SingleOrDefault();
```

I have been looking for a way to obtain the two conditions together, since the file passed in argument 0 may be open in a notepad in another language, so I have to work on a massive possibility unnecessarily, and not to, and edit the code to obtain the result in several languages for possible strings in the title of the notepad window in the current language of the system in use:

> `File_Name.eXtension - Notepad` // in: en-EU
> `File_Name.eXtension - Bloco de Notas` in: // en-BR

I'm trying something that looks like:

```
...

[DllImport("user32.dll")][return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);

...
String Title = args[0].ToLower()+ " - Notepad";

String Exec = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(args[1].ToLower());

Process process = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.MainWindowTitle
                == Title && p.ProcessName == Exec).SingleOrDefault();


if (process != null) 
{

    var wHnd = process.MainWindowHandle;

    if (!IsIconic(wHnd)) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("False"); // Maximized or Nommal Window: File - Notepad.exe // 
        return;
    }
    else if (IsIconic(wHnd));
    {
        Console.WriteLine("True"); // Minimized Window: File - Notepad.exe // 
        return; 
    }

}

Console.WriteLine("File not open!"); // Not Founded Windows //
```

With that, it would be possible to obtain bool for open file only when it was opened by notepad, tying the windowcondition and status already associated with `args[0]` and switched with `args[1]`.

I could add a call to cmd and make someone similar, then I would save the result and act according to the return, but it is very much back, and I understand that there must be something similar in a method, however, I believe that the expressions I used (my English is poor) ask not to have helped me find a method for the same processing...

```
wmic process where "Name like '%Notepad.exe%' and CommandLine like '%\\File_Name.eXtension%'" get process id.
```

---

The case of Notepad in particular, is that it can have a window name that varies according to the language of the windows, and is a pre-defined "standard" editor.

The case is summarized in how to obtain 2 conditions in a process,
where I will have a title in one condition and a process name in another condition.

Comment: What, specifically, is so interesting about the file being open in Notepad? What if it's open in another editor? Testing if a file is open in *any* editor, such that it cannot be opened for writing by you, is far simpler (just attempt to open it with the appropriate mode and see if it fails).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for you comment, this will run in background and intent do not “disturb” any current process with file... also, in arg[1] any editors can became used in/by defaults user settings..

Comment: What about just searching for `notepad.exe` processes like this `Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => Path.GetFileName(p.MainModule.FileName) == "notepad.exe")`

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for your suggest, but who to check 2 conditions, 1st is the file opened and 2nd the editor exec name.

Comment: This intent to check if the file name is open by another editor and not by the same passed by arg...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Where` filters all processes to those that match the condition. `SingleOrDefault` will search for a single process that matches the condition and if multiple or no process matches it will return `null`. This is what you should do:

```cs
Process process = Process
    .GetProcesses()
    .SingleOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowTitle == Title && p.ProcessName == Exec);
```